# adding a textbox dynamically with binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a TextBox control dynamically to my DataList ItemDataBound event. How do I programmatically bind the text property to my object?

```
void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Panel p1 = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        p1.Controls.Add(t1);    
        //need to add something like <%# Bind("MyProperty") %>    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.text =((YourClass)e.Item.DataItem).YourProperty
p1.Controls.Add(t1);
```

Comment: For the benefit of OP and other readers who might have the same problem, where in the given code would this line go?

Comment: @Popnoodles: Agreed.  It is unclear where this line of code should be placed.  Please clarify by editing your post.

Comment: Apologies, I've added a bit more detail.